# Counting the number of triangles inside $3-4-5-$triangle [Found in Arabic Math book: الرياضيات | هندسة الإحداثيات | الإحصاء]

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinations, coordinate-systems

While reading a pdf Arabic math book, counting chapter, I found this question:

[image]

> It says:
>
> The points $(0,0),(0,3),(4,0)$ are jointed to each other. Also, the
>   points:
>
> $(0,1),(0,2),(0.8,2.4),(1,0),(1.6,1.8),(2,0),(2.4,1.2),(3,0),(3.2,0.6)$
>   are jointed to each other and to the vertices of the $3-4-5-$triangle.
>   What is the total number of triangle? (Note: All triangles must be
>   considered).

---

I tried to use simple formulas of counting triangles in simple shapes, like the big triangle is divided by joining a straight line from a vertex to the opposite side, we just count the number of bases on the divided side, we apply the formula $N=n(n+1)/2$. Also for adjacent equilateral triangles we can use the formula $N=n(n+2)(2n+2)/8$ and then we round down, where $n$ is the number triangles on one side of the big one, .... and some other simple shapes. I tried to combine some of the together, but noway.

What I knew about the given points is to make fixed total number of triangles. Moving a point slightly may change the answer. THERE ARE SMALL TRIANGLES!

---

But this one is so complected, and without calculation, I think the total number of triangles is so large number. Maybe it is okay to keep the answer in a form containing factorials or $^aC_b$ or or $^aP_b$ such forms. I am not sure how to begin.

If the vertices of the triangles that to be counted lie on the boundaries of the $3-4-5-$triangle, then this is:

$$^{12}C_3-^6C_3-^5C_3-^4C_3=186$$

### But this is not the case, the required is to find the total number of possible triangles in the figure. Note: listing the coordinates implies an interest in the tiny triangles. Also, note that: because of these particular given coordinates, we have some intersection points of $3$ lines, and some of only $2$ lines, resulting some tiny triangles to be considered.

### *EDIT:*

Here is a big figure, I used desmos to make it:

[image]

---

Any help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: I'm interested in the book you used as a source.  Is there any  English translation?

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya unfortunately no. Because it is quit old book. Arab people translate English books, but it is rare when Arabic book to be translated.

Comment: To be clear: Are you saying that "All triangles must be considered" means that every triangular region must be counted? Or just the triangles whose vertices were listed? Your "THERE ARE SMALL TRIANGLES!" seems to be showing concern about the tiny triangular regions, but I can't tell for sure. Considering how small some of those regions are, one should reasonably fear that various lines that *look* concurrent actually bound even-tinier regions. The only way to be sure would be to verify with, say, Ceva's Theorem, but that amount of effort seems beyond the scope of a simple counting exercise.

Comment: @Blue Not just triangles whose vertices are listed, but all including tiny rectangular regions.

Comment: The usual such problem would count only triangles where all three vertices are on the three original edges of the large 3-4-5 triangle. When they say "all" it is most likely a reminder to allow triangles to be inside other such triangles. If so, we name the left leg ABCD, then the lower leg DEFGH, then the hypotenuse HIJKLA. The total number of triangle is the count of letter triples such as ADH  or BDH, BEI. Suggest you just write out the triples, there will be plenty... Wait, there does not need to be a vertex on each of three edges, FGI is legal.

Comment: @WillJagy if the case was not to count all triangles, then the coordinates of those points might not be listed. Also, it is mentioned as a note: (All triangles must be considered). I mean, including all (big and tiny).

Comment: Well, of course I am unable to judge the Arabic wording. I can see how you might feel that listing the coordinates implies an interest in the tiny triangles. However, that takes us from the medium level problem I describe to finding coordinates for the intersection of every pair of line segments, then confirm genuine small triangles, genuine triple intersections. I know exactly how to do it, but... I suppose the method changes from listing triples of vertices to triples of line segments...interesting, three line segments that intersect in pairs (in or on the 345) but not a triple intersection

Comment: @WillJagy Logically sir, if that was the case, then there will be $9$ lines inside the triangle plus $3$ lines that form the big triangle. So a total of $12$ lines. But we have $2$ points here; The first point, we have TONS of lines. And the second point, the coordinates of the points are given in that way, otherwise the number of rectangles will be changed. In your case, no need to mention the coordinates exactly in that way. THANKS :-)

Comment: ran out of space, three such lines make a triangle. It may be crossed y other lines, but would still count as one triangle. So, very long, but the only concern is triple intersections. Alright, I guess it can be done

Comment: @WillJagy actually we were writing the comments at the same time, what I wanted to say is: "I can see how you might feel that listing the coordinates implies an interest in the tiny triangles." Sorry for my poor English, at least we can try. Thanks dear :-)

Comment: I think there are more than 9 inside segments, because each vertex on a side of the 345 is joined to each point on the other two sides; granted, many of the segments are parallel to other segments...

Comment: @WillJagy well you are right more than $9$. It is so difficult problem but a nice one.

Comment: @WillJagy Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106861/discussion-between-hussain-alqatari-and-will-jagy).

Comment: Hussain-Alqatari, your last comment appears to have automatically made a chatroom. A link to the chat is there in place of your last comment

Comment: Are you looking for a purely mathematical solution? Or would you allow for one by way of image processing?

Comment: @user170231 May I know what do you mean by "way of image processing?"

Comment: I bet there is a practical solution that would involve importing your image into software in order to programmatically isolate every instance of a $3$-sided polygon. Something similar to the task in [this question at Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11725/how-to-find-circular-objects-in-an-image/).

Comment: @user170231 That sounds awesome; to do that using software. I want want a purely mathematical solution. But it will be nice to verify with that software, can you do it for verification? THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that expertise... But you could try posting your question there (unless that's against SE etiquette?)

Comment: @user170231 "there", where?

Comment: [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I can't decide if this is a math problem, or if it only becomes a math problem if someone finds an interesting solution. My personal (un-interesting) answer is "infinity" if we are allowed to form the vertices at arbitrary points inside the big triangle, not necessarily intersection points.

Answer (score 4):

In order to take an accurate census of the number of triangles inhabiting the $3-4-5$ Pythagorean triangle--an ancient city with three walls, twelve gates, and thirty-five gate-to-gate streets, as can be seen from OP's illustration,--I found it necessary to reconstruct the city one street at a time and count the successive generations of inhabitants as they appear along each new street.

**I.** Although easy enough at first, the need for a method soon became apparent. In triangle $ABC$, with $AB$, $AC$, $CB$ divided at $D$, $E$, $F$, $G$, $H$, $I$, $J$, $K$, $L$, joining segments $AI$, $AJ$, $AK$, $AL$ in succession produces two, three, four, and five new triangles.

Next, joining $BG$, $BH$ produces twenty and twenty-five more triangles, which I determined by the following method.
[image: counting method]
With $BH$ the last line drawn, first count the three new triangles having $BH$ for a side: $ABH$, $GBH$, $CBH$.

Then take $Q$, the point next most distant from $B$ and the intersection of $BH$ with $AI$. With those lines as analogous to axes in coordinate geometry, making quadrants $IQB$, $IQH$, $HQA$, $AQB$, count all triangles having the new point $Q$ for vertex, beginning with with the largest triangle in each quadrant and working inward toward $Q$. Thus in the first quadrant $IQB$ we have triangle $IQB$; in $IQH$, no triangle; in $HQA$, triangle $HQA$; in $AQB$, triangles $AQB$, $AQT$, $AQS$, $AQR$, $PQB$.

Next, around point $R$ as vertex, in quadrants $JRB$, $JRH$, $HRA$, $ARB$ we find triangle $JRB$ in the first quadrant, none in the second, $HRA$ in the third ($QRA$ has already been counted), and $ARB$, $ART$, $ARS$, $ORB$ in the fourth.

Similarly with $S$ as vertex we get triangles $KSB$; none; $HSA$ ($HRA$, $HQA$ have already been counted); and $ASB$, $AST$, $NSB$.

Finally with $T$ as vertex we have triangles $LTB$; none; $HTA$; and $ATB$, $MTB$.

Summing up the new triangles:$$3+7+6+5+4=25$$

**II.** When $CD$, $CE$, $CF$ have been joined, as in the next figure, three-line concurrencies appear at points $O$ and $S$. Taking $CF$, the last line drawn, note that any triangles within sectors $KSB$, $KSH$, $HSA$, $ASB$ were already counted when $BH$ was joined. 
There is now, however, an octant of new sectors around $S$ to be examined for new triangles:$$CSB, CSK, CSH, CSA, BSF, KSF, HSF, ASF$$(There appear to be seventeen three-line concurrencies when all thirty-five lines have been drawn in triangle $ABC$, each requiring that we search for new triangles in eight sectors instead of four.)
[image: 3-line concurrencies]
As $CD$, $CE$, $CF$ are successively joined, I count thirty-five, forty-three, and forty-seven triangles generated. Thus with the original triangle, when all nine lines from vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, are joined in the above order, the number of triangles is$$1+2+3+4+5+20+25+35+43+47=185$$

Twenty-six lines remain to be joined.

**III.** The seven segments $GI$, $GJ$, $GK$, $GL$, $GF$, $GE$, $GD$ generate$$26+41+56+74+65+58+52=372$$new triangles, bringing the triangle population now to$$185+372=557$$Segment $GJ$ passes through $C'$, making a third three-line concurrency as seen in the next figure.
[image: next seven lines]

**IV.** The next seven segments $HI$, $HJ$, $HK$, $HL$, $HF$, $HE$, $HD$ generate$$24+43+70+102+133+139+148=659$$more triangles, bringing the count to $$557+659=1216$$Segment $HE$ brings in a fourth and fifth three-line concurrency, and $HD$ a sixth. I leave the figure unlettered except for the points of 3-line concurrency.
[image: and another seven]

**V.** The remaining twelve segments$$DI, DJ, DK, DL, EI, EJ, EK, EL, FI, FJ, FK, FL$$make$$16, 12, 11, 8, 14, 12, 8, 4, 16, 12, 6, 2$$intersections, respectively, within triangle $ABC$, each intersection a center of four (or eight) sectors to be searched for additional triangles. By using, for each new line drawn, the method explained above, I count$$232+186+155+117+239+188+139+89+249+183+117+62=1956$$new triangles, for a total of$$1216+1956=3172$$within the $3-4-5$ triangle.

I have indicated the order in which I have drawn the lines, and the number of new triangles I found for each line. I could in more detail also give the number of new triangles for each intersection point on a given line, as well as for each of the four (or eight sectors) around that point, in order to compare notes with anyone interested in this search of the Pythagorean triangle. I think this is a reliable way to find the number of triangles in the $3-4-5$ triangle, and to guard against leaving out any triangle or counting any triangle twice. It's laborious, but I don't see how combinatorial theory alone can yield an answer; the seventeen three-line concurrencies affect the count, and they arise from the geometry of the case being considered. But to proceed by counting, intersection points must be labeled, and things get very crowded and confusing to the eye, since the number of intersections generally increases as more lines are drawn. I relied greatly on GeoGebra's capacity to zoom in, and even to temporarily hide labels when they get too crowded. The figure below shows seventeen points of three-line concurrency.
[image: 3-line concurrency]

Comment: Hello dear, thanks for answering. It is doubtful if the number of triangles is $3172$ or $3201$. Can you please check the following link, and see if one, or both answers are wrong. Thanks. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222896/counting-the-number-of-triangles-inside-3-4-5-triangle-found-in-arabic-math-b

Comment: I'm glad to find myself disagreeing by less than 1% from the result obtained by @Michael Seifert.  I'd be interested to know if we at least agree about the seventeen three-line concurrencies.  If not, we can try to sort that out.  If we agree on that, then all I can do is try a recount; I have no software or machinery besides GeoGebra to help me.

Comment: Wait! .. in AQB, we have AQB, AQT, AQS.... but why you considered PQR? (Second paragraph after the first figure)

Comment: It's $AQB$, $AQT$, $AQS$, $AQR$, $PQB$.

Comment: Really sorry dear. It was because looking at triangles and points, counting, solving equations, for continuous couple of hours on this problem. I was not focusing well. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very elegant, but might be improved. I will describe the really primitive version. Any triangle will have one side that joins the x-axis to the y-axis, one that joins the x-axis to the hypotenuse, and one that joins the y-axis to the hypotenuse. We can choose one vertex from each side in fewer that 3x4x5=60 ways, and the three lines corresponding to each choice of triple all have rather simple equations that can be put into the form $a_ix+b_iy=1$ We lose the opportunity to make a triangle if the lines have a common point and this happens if $$det\begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1& 1\\a_2&b_2&1\\a_3&b_3&1\end{pmatrix}=0$$
All of the algebra could be done using fractional arithmetic, leaving the answer in no doubt.

ADDED
The problem does not change if the triangle undergoes an affine transformation. Let new vertices be placed at (0,0),(1,0),(0,1). Then the points on the triangle are the three sets
$$A:[(0,1/3),(0,2/3),(0,1)]\\
B:[(0,0),(1/4,0),(1/2,0),(3/4,0)]\\
C:[(1,0),(4/5,1/5),(3/5,2/5),(2/5,3/5),(1/5,4/5)]
$$
Then we choose one point each from A and B, and find the line joining them. Say this line has the class AB.
Then take one point each from B and C and join them (line of class BC), next one point each from C and A (line of class CA). In this way we produce all the lines in your diagram. Choosing one line from each class will find all possible triangles, 
unless the determinant vanishes.

Comment: THANKS for this, but are you considering every possible triangles, (even tiny ones). A vertex of a possible triangle may or may not lie on the 3-4-5-triangle. As mentioned in the question, all triangle MUST be considered. But in your way, I think, the only considered triangles are those who have at least one vertex on the 3-4-5-triangle. Please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hussein  The sides of the tiny triangles extend to the specified points, but the vertices of those triangles may be anywhere.

Comment: "Any triangle will have one side that joins the x-axis to the y-axis, one that joins the x-axis to the hypotenuse, and one that joins the y-axis to the hypotenuse." — this is false.  Consider the lines $[(0,1/3), (2/5,3/5)]$, $[(0,2/3), (3/5,2/5)]$, and $[(0,1), (1/4,0)]$.  These three lines intersect inside the triangle, but only one of them intersects the $x$-axis.