# Counting number of triangles inside an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Can someone help me with an algorithm to count the number of triangles inside an equilateral triangle, with multiple lines drawn from every angle of the triangle, where no three different lines from distinct corners cross at one point. Example:

[image: triangle]

Overlapping triangles can be ignored.

*Maybe it is possible to apply some graph theory theorems? I seems every (inner) intersection is a vertex with degree = 4. Knowing that and using degrees of vertices of the corners, would that tell us anything?*

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: What are my thoughts? I'm surprised and proud of myself that I spelled "equilateral triangle" correctly. I have no ideas. This is way out of my league, yet I still want to solve it. Can you help, without condescending and downvoting, or should I go post this somewhere where monkey-brained simpletons like me would usually go? Maybe reddit or something?

Comment: Sorry, that sounded pretty mean. I meant it to be only sarcastic.

Comment: Perhaps you can consult [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) on how to ask a good question.  You will be more likely to receive an answer if you do.

Comment: If there are no triple intersections, the triangles can be counted by labeling all the line (segments, including the original sides) and counting triples of lines that intersect properly so as to bound a triangle. For that question, other lines passing through a triangle do not matter. The question fr all polygons differs violently. Suggest you take your diagram but with just some of the lines, count carefully...

Comment: @WillJagy oh, I had not clue it would be very different for non-triangles. I will remove it from the question then.

Comment: I don't understand : it seems to me there is a contradiction between your title and your text where you consider only triangles, therefore excluding n-gons... (n=$4,5,6...$) ? Could you tell for example how many triangles you count in this figure ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I based my comment on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3630441/counting-the-number-of-triangles-inside-3-4-5-triangle-found-in-arabic-math-b   For me, every triple of line (segments) that intersect pairwise in or on the outer triangle, but no more than two out of three edges meeting the vertices of the big triangle, should be counted as a triangle. My take is that this OP wants an algorithm but is not interested in, say, adding a simpler diagram and showing his work  on that.